# Duration calculation in seconds

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is what my data looks like. How do I calculate the duration, in seconds. I've tried some an answer but it looks complicated -

```
=INT(E226-D226)&" days "&TEXT(MOD(E226-D226,1),"hh "" hours ""mm"" minutes ""ss"" seconds""")  


Start_Time  End_Time    Duration  
20:37:31    20:37:31    
20:21:45    20:32:57    
18:55:42    20:45:31
```

Thanks

Comment: You say "Duration calculation in seconds" but the formula you quote gives you days, hours, minutes and seconds...and the data shown doesn't include dates, so implies that you can't get days in the result - Can you give the exact results you want?

Answer (score 3):

Excel datetimes are stored internally as numbers where 1.0 represents one day and 1/24 represents one hour and so on.

There are 86400 seconds in a day so the duration in seconds is:

```
= (END - START) * 86400
```

Comment: 86400 <=> 24*60*60